# Order of authors in footnote in elsarticle

Tags: pdftex, elsarticle, affiliation

my friends.

I am preparing a latex file in elsarticle format. The below code is my MWE.

```
  \documentclass[review,3p,times,fleqn]{elsarticle}
  \usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false,raiselinks=true,colorlinks,linktoc=all]{hyperref}‎
  \begin{document}‎
  \begin{frontmatter}‎
  %----------------------------------------------------
  %          ‎Title of Paper‎
  %----------------------------------------------------
  \title{Computation of flow and heat transfer}‎
  %----------------------------------------------------
  %          ‎Author Names‎
  %----------------------------------------------------
  %% ‎Group authors per affiliation‎:
  \author[label1]{\textcolor{blue}{Mohammad Fazli}}‎
  \ead{mohammad.fazli@ut.ac.ir}‎
  %-------------
  \author[label1]{\textcolor{blue}{Mehrdad Raisee}\corref{cor1}}
  \ead{mraisee@ut.ac.ir}‎
  %-------------
  \cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author‎}‎
  %----------------------------------------------------
  %          ‎Author's Affiliations‎
  %----------------------------------------------------
  \address[label1]{‎Hydraulic Machinery Research Institute‎, ‎School of Mechanical Engineering‎, ‎College of Engineering‎, ‎University of Tehran‎, ‎Tehran‎, ‎P.O‎. ‎Box‎: ‎11155-4563‎, ‎Iran}‎‎
  \end{frontmatter}‎
  \section{Bibliography styles}‎
  In another study‎, ‎Hwang et al‎. measured the local distribution of heat transfer coefficient and thermal performance in a channel with a staggered array of dimples and protrusions‎. 
  \end{document}
```

As I mentioned, I am using the elsearticle class. My problem is in my affiliation and its footer section. I have set "mohammad fazli" and "mehrdad raisee" in affiliation section, respectively. But I want to set these names with a reverse order at the footer. I mean email of mehrdad raisee and email of mohammad fazli at the footer. Can anybody help me?

I mean:

names:

mohammad fazli, mehrdad raisee

footer:

email of mehrdad raisee, email of mohammad fazli

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your objective fully: You want M. Fazli to be listed before M. Raisee in the list of authors, *and* you want their email addresses to be stated in the reverse order: `mraisee@ut.ac.ir` *before* `mohammad.fazli@ut.ac.ir`. Moreover, the authors share the same mailing address. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: As you mentioned, I want to have a reverse order of names in the footer relative to the affiliation parts. My purpose is just this. I don't want truly share the mail addresses.

Comment: I'm afraid your follow-up comment didn't really clarify things. For instance, in your sample code, you list just one mailing address, which is common to both authors; yet in the follow-up comment, you mention "mail addresses", in plural form. Are these two sentences referring to the same item? And, what exactly do you mean by "shar[ing]" mail addresses? Please clarify.

Comment: I mentioned two emails in the footer (mohammad.fazli@ut.ac.ir & mraisee@ut.ac.ir). These mails are hyperlinked to their names in the affiliation (above part of paper under the title). Now, I want to change the order of mails in footer relative to affiliation names. Do you need further aim?

Comment: Sorry, I just don't understand you're trying to achieve. My bad. Apologies. Maybe somebody else can figure it out, though.